# Equivalent functionality of Matlab sortrows() in MathNET.Numerics?

Tags: matlab, mathnet-numerics

Is there a MathNET.Numerics equivalent of Matlab’s `sortrows(A, column)`, where A is a `Matrix<double>`?

To recall [Matlab's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html):

> B = sortrows(A,column) sorts A based on the columns specified in the
> vector column. For example, sortrows(A,4) sorts the rows of A in
> ascending order based on the elements in the fourth column.
> sortrows(A,[4 6]) first sorts the rows of A based on the elements in
> the fourth column, then based on the elements in the sixth column to
> break ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to my answer to your other question, there's nothing inbuilt but you could use [`Linq`'s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netcore-3.1) [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) method on an `Enumerable` of the matrix's rows. Given a `Matrix<double> x`,

`x.EnumerateRows()` returns an `Enumerable<Vector<double>>` of the matrix's rows. You can then sort this enumerable by the first element of each row (if that's what you want).

In C#,

```cs
var y = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(x.EnumerateRows().OrderBy(row => row[0]));
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rPNFVJ)

Writing this as an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```cs
public static Matrix<double> SortRows(this Matrix<double> x, int sortByColumn = 0, bool desc = false) {
    if (desc)
        return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(x.EnumerateRows().OrderByDescending(row => row[sortByColumn]));
    else
        return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(x.EnumerateRows().OrderBy(row => row[sortByColumn]));
}
```

which you can then call like so:

```cs
var y = x.SortRows(0); // Sort by first column
```

[Here's a big fiddle containing everything](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LOk40M)