# Equivalent functionality of Matlab unique() in MathNET.Numerics?

Tags: c#, matlab, mathnet-numerics

Is there a MathNET.Numerics equivalent of Matlab’s `unique(A, 'rows')` (or `unique(A)`), where `A` is a `Matrix<double>`?

I have searched extensively through the MathNET.Numerics library documentation, and cannot find anything resembling this functionality. Does similar functionality already exist?

To recall Matlab's documentation:

> C = unique(A,'rows') treats each row of A as a single entity and
> returns the unique rows of A. The rows of the array C are in sorted
> order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inbuilt, but you could use `Linq`'s [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1) method on an `Enumerable` of the matrix's rows. Given a `Matrix<double> x`,

```
var y = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(x.EnumerateRows().Distinct());
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SExkpQ)

Writing this as an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static Matrix<double> Unique(this Matrix<double> x) {
    return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(x.EnumerateRows().Distinct());
}
```

Which you can then call as:

```
var y = x.Unique();
```

This doesn't sort the rows. If you want that, you could combine this with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64466693/843953).

```
public static Matrix<double> UniqueSorted(this Matrix<double> x, int sortByColumn = 0, bool desc = false) {
    var uq = x.EnumerateRows().Distinct();
    if (desc)
        return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(uq.OrderByDescending(row => row[sortByColumn]));
    else
        return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRows(uq.OrderBy(row => row[sortByColumn]));
}
```

[Here's a big fiddle containing everything](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LOk40M)

Comment: One additional aspect of `unique()` is that it sorts as well. I'll need to add a sorting mechanism in there too, but otherwise this works.

Comment: That's fairly simple to add and I modified my answer. I'm not a big fan of Matlab's sorting of the matrix unless you explicitly specify that you don't want it sorted, so I like having two separate functions for them. If you'd like it in a single function, it's easy enough to do.